# groovy ObjectGraphBuilder build complex object from Java objects not groovy objects

Tags: groovy

i'm using ObjectGraphBuilder to build a complex object.  is there a way to build it based off of existing java objects, and not groovy objects?  thanks

update 8/16: here's the code that doesn't work, as well as the exception i get.  The only groovy code is MyMain.groovy.  everything else is java.

```
public class Company {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Employee {
   private String name;
   private int employeeId;   
   //getters and setters
}

public class Address {
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    private int zip;
    private String state;
    //getters and setters
}

class MyMain {
    def company

    Company createCompany() {
    def builder = new ObjectGraphBuilder()
    company = builder.company(name: 'ACME'){
        address(line1: '32 fifth st', line2: 'apt 423')     
        3.times {
            employee(employeeId: 20, name: 'joe smith')         
        }
    }
    }   
 }

 public class Blah {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyMain myMain = new MyMain();
     Company c = myMain.createCompany();
     System.out.println(c.getName());
     System.out.println(c.getAddress().getLine1());
     System.out.println(c.getAddress().getLine2());     
     System.out.println("tot # of employees " + c.getEmployees().size());   
     }
 }

 Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Employee@152441a' with class 'Employee' to class 'java.util.List'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:360)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2465)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3412)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:196)
```

**UPDATE 2**
turns out you have to initialize the list.  so, if you put

```
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

then, it'll work.  What about for arrays though?  i tried creating an empty array, but that didn't work.  it'll run without any exceptions, but the size of the array will only be 1 regardless of how many employee statements i have in my builder.

```
 employee(employeeId: 20, name: 'joe smith')
 employee(employeeId: 10, name: 'geno smith')
 employee(employeeId: 80, name: 'your mom')
```

i've noticed that if you iterate through the array, whatever is the last employee you specified in the builder will end up being the one in the array.

Comment: I assume you've had problems doing it?  Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: This is basic Java. Refer the example again in the page where POGOs are used. `employees` was initialized to an empty list `List employees = []`, now that has to be done in Java as well right? If you want I can post the same exercise you are doing right now. I did not want to showcase in the first place while answering because I wanted you to do this exercise explicitly which will be more fruitful to the learning curve. :) PS:- Delete the other answer, add your updates to the main question as above.

Comment: well, yeah, your example works just fine.  but i'm asking how to do it if i'm using POJOs, not POGOs.  and, the problem i'm having is how to do it if it's an array of Employee.  i've tried initializing it to an empty array, akin to initializing the List to an empty list, but it's not producing what i want.

Comment: Clone [this sample groovy project](https://github.com/dmahapatro/groovy-object-graph-sample) and run the test.

Comment: Was the answer and sample project helpful in anyways?

Answer (score 2):

It should work with Java classes as good as Groovy classes. Groovy class is ultimately compiled to byte code as Java. So there should not be any problem.

Refer example in [groovy docs for ObjectGraphBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ObjectGraphBuilder) to see how it works with POGO. Replace them with POJOs in a project, you would see the same behavior.

Comment: i tried replacing POGOs with POJOs, and it seems to work ok.  the only problem is if i'm trying to populate a collection.  My POJO looks has a member `List<Employee> employees`.  But, if i do `3.times {
    employee(employeeId: 20, name: 'joe smith')}`, i get an exception.  `Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Employee@1f530ab' with class 'Employee' to class 'java.util.List'`

Comment: @user2687884 Can you post a runnable example that fails in your question?  Comments aren't the place for long chunks of code

Answer (score 0):

turns out you have to initialize the list.  so, if you put

```
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

then, it'll work.  What about for arrays though?  i tried creating an empty array, but that didn't work.  it'll run without any exceptions, but the size of the array will only be 1 regardless of how many employee statements i have in my builder.

```
 employee(employeeId: 20, name: 'joe smith')
 employee(employeeId: 10, name: 'geno smith')
 employee(employeeId: 80, name: 'your mom')
```

i've noticed that if you iterate through the array, whatever is the last employee you specified in the builder will end up being the one in the array.